# Run two Java programs from Eclipse at once?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am building a Java Google App Engine server project and a Java desktop client. I would like to run them both at once, but I'm not sure if this is possible using Eclipse/GAE plugin. Is there some way? I'd like to be able to step through them both at the same time.

I tried opening a new instance of Eclipse, but it complained that the workspace is already in use, both projects are in the same workspace. (Perhaps I could just move them to different workspaces.)

Comment: is it necessary to run them from eclipse?

Comment: I'd like to be able to debug them both at the same time, but it's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to launch multiple Java programs with one configuration on separate consoles (with Eclipse)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316761/how-to-launch-multiple-java-programs-with-one-configuration-on-separate-consoles), but the accepted answer here has good info about pinning consoles.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the GAE and if that interferes, but I don't have a problem running multiples. I often fire up a server and multiple clients from the same window.

A few pointers:

- Go to the main method of each program to run them. Once you've run them once, they show up in the drop menu on the run button.
- Make multiple consoles and pin them. It makes it much easier to see your (debug/informational) outputs in real time.
- Move the multiple consoles to separate views so you can see them at the same time.

Before on top, after on bottom
[image]

Comment: Do you mean open multiple Eclipse console tabs, or multiple OS command prompts? If it's from Eclipse, how do you open multiple console tabs?

Comment: @rosarch added picture to illustrate step by step multiple consoles.

Comment: I successfully added a new console view, but it's just two views of the same data, not two separate programs running. Are you sure this works?

Comment: @Rosarch You need to pin the consoles, so the output of one process doesn't come into focus on the other. The *Pin* icon is to the left of the *Open Console* icon. Then you have to choose the running instance by clicking the down arrow on the *Display Selected Console* icon.

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fconsole%2Fref-pin_action.htm

Answer (score 10):

After adding the new Console view, you must go to the icon to its left and select which console you want to see. If you're running two programs you will see the two programs in the drop down list.

Thanks for the answers. I was just trying it out and it was really helpful.

(By icon to the left I mean the one that looks like a mini purple color monitor)

Comment: the mini purple color monitor clue was key 

Answer (score 2):

@Corsika answer explains how to run on Eclipse

If you are comfortable running on two or more programs on the terminal
you can copy command line args from the debug view for different launch configurations and run on two or more terminals!!

To get the full command line, you can open the Debug view from Window>Show View>Other>debug

Now after run> Right click on the last launch(debug tab) and go to properties. Eclipse will list the exact command line.