# Running multiple files in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, distributed

I am doing a distributed systems project & I want to run multiple servers  (of a same file ) by eclipse at the same time on my local system,

Is it possible to do that ? generally, is it possible to run multiple files (e.g. a client and a server) on one eclipse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly launch multiple launch configuration at once: there is an [old bug still pending](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=39900), which involves the ["launch group" option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053265/eclipse-running-multiple-launch-configurations-at-once/11905444#11905444)  (present in the  "C/C++ Development Tools" plugin, but usable for other non-C++ project.

But you can run multiple launch configuration one after the other.
As illustrated in "[Run two Java programs from Eclipse at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453894/run-two-java-programs-from-eclipse-at-once)", you will have multiple console.
And you can script that launch sequence with [escript](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/escripts).

Answer (score 0):

If by file you mean program, yes.

Comment: How can I do that ? because I can run multiple files but I have only one console , which is only for one program running , and when I want to compile and run a file (here : program) I can only run it once

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can start multiple servers one by one, and then swith to your program want to run. and run again directly.  Or you can set up many run configurations manuly and then run them one by one. Any unclear pls point out.

Comment: but isn't it always one console in eclipse ? I'd like to see the result for each of these components which are connected to each other simultaneously