# Java Socket Chat in Eclipse

Tags: java, sockets, chat, firewall

I'm trying to implement a websocket chatroom type of interface. Everything compiles, but when I run the code I get an error on the client side actually connecting to the server.

I've found this question: [Run two Java programs from Eclipse at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453894/run-two-java-programs-from-eclipse-at-once) and thought that this was my issue. However even after running the programs as they suggest, (pinning the consoles and such) I still get an error about the connection.

The only thing I can think of is possibly some firewall setting I have on my system (running on localhost) that I might need to change? Other than that maybe someone can help me understand why the connection is not working?

```
public class EchoServer
{
    public static final int LISTENING_PORT = 19903;
    public static final int MAX_CLIENTS = 4;
```

Client:

```
public class Client
{
    public static final String SERVER_HOSTNAME = "localhost";
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 11516;
```

Comment: Nothing about your code seems to be WebSocket related.  Looks like standard Socket code.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Apparently terminology is not my strong suit. I've updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Client class the variable SERVER_PORT should be equal to variable LISTENING_PORT in the EchoServer class.

Comment: Honestly can't believe I missed that. Sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes. Thanks so much!