# How to get multiple console for different projects running on tomcat server?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, console

I am new to eclipse and I'm working with **eclipse + tomcat Server** where many dynamic web application projects are available for testing and developing.

Now I am working on one of the project in eclipse and on server there are 3 projects deployed and running and showing console output to trace the errors and debug information by switching.

But I **need to show different console for different project running on tomcat**.

Referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453894/run-two-java-programs-from-eclipse-at-once) but it's working with main method I don't have that one in web application.

Tried but getting same output in all console window

[image]

I don't know it's possible or not but if yes then please help me.

Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: Yes , you can open. See , for instance you have 3 consoles for your web projects , then look at `computer icon` (display selected console) in bottom part , click on down arrow. You can see all the consoles for your project. click on any one of console . after that next to computer icon `open console` icon is there  in that select `new console view`. Do it for all 3 consoles so that you can have three different console tabs .

Comment: Sorry but I am getting same output on every console for all web applications running on server same server I think it is because of same server for all running project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After too much hard work I found the solution :)

**Step 1: Get into server area.**

```
      `Eclipse -> Window -> Show view -> Servers.`
```

**Step 2: Get into server configuration area.**

```
      `Servers window -> Select server -> double click on server.`
```

**Step 3: Change server setting.**

```
      `Server Locations -> Select Use Tomcat installation.
```

(takes control of tomcat installation.)`

**Step 4: Start projects.**

```
      `Start every project you want to run in different consol.`
```

**Step 5: Open new console**

```
     `Select console menu (from right side of console) -> New console view.`
```

**Step 6: Select project**

```
     `Select consol -> Display selected console -> select project server.`
```

There you go....

Comment: `Server Locations -> Select Use Tomcat installation.` option is disabled in my eclipse

Comment: Stop server and delete all projects under the server. Then it will be enabled.

Comment: I tried this in Luna, and was able to take control of the Tomcat installation.  But when I started the server, the different projects weren't listed separately under the console.  The only item in the console menu was named after the server.....