# Start mutliple java applications at once in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

Just for convenience ...

I am working on a project with multiple spring boot apps. Is there a way to create a Run Configuration in eclipse that starts multiple apps with one click?

Currently I have to go through all the different configs using the drop down menu.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053265/eclipse-running-multiple-launch-configurations-at-once)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453894/run-two-java-programs-from-eclipse-at-once

Comment: Found especially this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11905444/1493204 answer very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the extension "C/C++ Development Tools" from the CDT also works for  Java development. And it offers "Launch Groups" which are exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The upcoming Spring Tools Suite (based on eclipse) has a nice Spring Boot dashboard feature. You can get the release candidate previews here:

http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/index.html

You can select multiple boot apps in the dashboard then click on the "play" button to launch them all at once.