# read write from server and client both side in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, client-server

I've the code for server and client classes. I've two classes, ServerApp working as server and ClientApp working as client in my local machine.

I first run the ServerApp class and then the ClientApp class. After running the ClientApp class I write some message in the eclipse console "Hello Server" then the message is printed in ServerApp console displaying the client message.

But when I run the ServerApp class and write some text in console and running the ClientApp does not display any message in the console.

I can not understand how to show two way message communication in eclipse console? Please suggest how I can perform two way communication (client server) in eclipse.

Server App

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ServerApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            ServerSocket Server_Socket;
            Server_Socket = new ServerSocket(5555);

            Socket clientSocket = null;
            clientSocket = Server_Socket.accept();

            DataInputStream input;
            input = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(input.readUTF());

            DataOutputStream output;
            output = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String str = "", str2 = "";
            while (!str.equals("stop")) 
            {
                str = input.readUTF();
                System.out.println("client says: " + str);
                str2 = br.readLine();
                output.writeUTF(str2);
                output.flush();
            }
            input.close();
            clientSocket.close();
            Server_Socket.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Client App

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ClientApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Socket Client_Socket;
            Client_Socket = new Socket("localhost", 5555);

            DataInputStream input;
            input = new DataInputStream(Client_Socket.getInputStream());

            DataOutputStream output;
            output = new DataOutputStream(Client_Socket.getOutputStream());

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String str = "", str2 = "";
            while (!str.equals("stop")) {
                str = br.readLine();
                output.writeUTF(str);
                output.flush();
                str2 = input.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Server says: " + str2);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            Client_Socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: There's an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453894/run-two-java-programs-from-eclipse-at-once)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run two Java programs from Eclipse at once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453894/run-two-java-programs-from-eclipse-at-once)